# Range.Left V/s Shape.Left

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook with five sheet. Each sheet has a print area defined and i want to insert word art at right top corner of the print area. I am using the below code for it. 
The problem is shape appears anywhere in the sheet and not right top corner of print area.
Any Suggestion ?

```
Sub test()

    Dim col As String, row As Long, rng As Range
    Dim sht As Worksheet, str_val As String
  Dim shp As Shape
    For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
       str_val = sht.Name & vbNewLine & "YM" & vbNewLine & Date
       sht.Activate

       If ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea <> vbNullString Then
         col = Split(ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea, "$")(3)
         row = Range(ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea).Cells(1).row
         str_val = sht.Name & vbNewLine & "YM" & vbNewLine & Date
         Set rng = Cells(row, col)
         Set shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddTextEffect(msoTextEffect28, str_val, "+mn-lt", 20, msoTrue, msoFalse, rng.Left, rng.Top)

       End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Thanks for looking into it.

Comment: Why do you add your text as a shape ? Wouldn't it be simpler to add your text directly in the cell using `Cells(row,col) = str_val`

Comment: @d-stroyer Its a requirement in project.

Comment: what kind of code do you get when you record mving the shape to the right place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
Sub Tester()

Dim shp As Shape, rngTR As Range, pa As Range
Dim t, l

    Set pa = ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea)
    Set rngTR = pa.Rows(1).Cells(pa.Columns.Count)

    Set shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddTextEffect(msoTextEffect28, _
                     "Hello World", "+mn-lt", 20, msoTrue, _
                     msoFalse, rngTR.Left, rngTR.Top)

     'adjust for shape width
    shp.Left = shp.Left - (shp.Width - rngTR.Width)

End Sub
```